# Reading stdout/sdterr of subprocesses in a thread-safe manner

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following class to call subprocesses from my application and read their stdout and stderr. Since there are no instance variables for this class, I would have thought it to be thread-safe, but without the `lock (_lockObject)` I can reproduce an error where the stdout of a subprocess is incorrectly reported as empty.

```
public class SubprocessRepository
{
    private readonly static object _lockObject = new Object();

    public ProcessReturnInfo Call(string fileName, params string[] args)
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            var joinedArguments = String.Join(" ", args);
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = String.Format(@"""{0}""", fileName),
                    Arguments = joinedArguments,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                }
            };

            // read the stdout and stderr streams asynchronously. if they are read synchronously and the streams fill up,
            // the entire process waits for the stream to be consumed which will never happen and the subprocess will be
            // never complete its operation
            var sortSdtOut = new StringBuilder();
            var sortSdtErr = new StringBuilder();
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sendingProcess, outLine) =>
            {
                // Collect the sort command output. 
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
                {
                    // Add the text to the collected output.
                    sortSdtOut.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
                }
            };
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sendingProcess, outLine) =>
            {
                // Collect the sort command output. 
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
                {
                    // Add the text to the collected output.
                    sortSdtErr.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
                }
            };

            process.Start();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit(15 * 60 * 1000);  // N minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds

            if (!process.HasExited)
            {
                process.Kill();  // executes asynchronously
                process.WaitForExit(10000);
            }

            return new ProcessReturnInfo
            {
                ExitCode = process.ExitCode,
                StdOut = sortSdtOut.ToString().Trim('\r', '\n'),
                StdErr = sortSdtErr.ToString().Trim('\r', '\n')
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I have done some reading on the topic but everything seems to suggest putting locks around the class' instance variables. I suspect it's something to do with the event-handling delegates, but am a bit unsure.

What is the cause of the thread-unsafety in this code when the lock is absent?

FYI, one of the processes that is being called (and incorrectly returning an empty string) is the following Powershell script:

```
Param(
    [string]$server_name,
    [string]$service_name
)


$path = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server_name -query "SELECT PathName FROM Win32_Service WHERE DisplayName = '$service_name'").PathName
if ($path -eq $null) {
    Write-Error "The $service_name Windows service does not exist on the target server."
    exit 1
} else {
    Write-Host $path
}
```

Comment: No, that's not how the Process class works.  The more logical interpretation is that the problem is located in the program you start, it just misbehaves when two instances of it run at the same time.  Doing something like creating a file, the 2nd instance corrupts the file created by the 1st instance.  Just an example, anything is possible.

Comment: I would have thought something like that @HansPassant, but the script I'm calling (which I've put in the question) is so innocent that I can't imagine there being misbehaviour.

Comment: Hmm, Powershell does pretty screwy things to make itself compatible with a console.  Just eliminate the failure mode, use the System.Management namespace to run WMI queries.

Comment: That seems like a pretty reasonable thing to try @HansPassant. I'll give it a go and report back about its success

Comment: Yeah Powershell was the problem @HansPassant, I've replaced all calls to it with usage of the `System.Management` namespace and I don't have any problems now. If you write an answer I'll accept it.